# Blender 3D: importing python modules like sklearn and yaml give error ModuleNotFoundError while they are already installed

Tags: python, import, blender

I have been trying to import modules like sklearn and yaml in the python script I have used to run in blender but they always give the error ModuleNotFoundError, I tried re-installing the modules but it still gives the same error. How do I import them?

Comment: How did you install them?

Comment: You are probably installing into your system copy of python, blender has its own copy of python. There are [several options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294734/2684771) like installing into blenders python or making blender use the system python.